# A function in child class inherited from a parent class uses that ones variables?

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

I have a little problem understanding what's wrong here.

I have code similiar to this one

```
Public Class Parent
    Public name As String = "dad"


    Public Function sayname() As String
        Return name
    End Function
End Class

Public Class child
    Inherits Parent
    Shadows name As String = "son"
End Class
```

When I do this:

```
dim littleson as new child
littleson.sayname()
```

it will return "dad", I want it to return "son". What's wrong with what I do?

Comment: Every new instance of `parent` is explicitly setting the name: `johnstruc.name = name`  Since Parent.Name is dad they are all dad

Comment: Don't use structures.  And the one you created makes no sense.  Child shouldn't inherit from Parent.  Maybe a base class called Person or Human would make more logical sense to inherit from.

Comment: but I never declared a "parent"? Judging from what I read - or at least what I understood from that - was, that "shadows" is supposed to alter the attribute "name" in the instances of "child" - and since I didn't declare a Parent, I am still lost.

Comment: @LarsTech I totally get your point, I just wrote it down as close to my real world situation as I could get. My Point is, that the "child" class inherits from "parent"-class. and the structure in Real world would be more complex.  That said it probably wouldn't change a thing if I left that one out and would declare a function 
`sayname() as string
return name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't shadow it, just set the value in the constructor.

```
Public Class Child
    Inherits Parent

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        name = "son"
    End Sub

End Class
```

Shadows creates a new variable completely different from the one in the parent.

Comment: forget what I wrote, message received. :-D
Thank you very much, that is so obvious and still I spent 2 hours not seeing it.